# Cannot properly import MODIS MOD07_L2 .hdf files into R using rgdal

Tags: raster, r, modis, rgdal

I've been trying to accurately import and process some .hdf files from the MODIS Atmospheric Profile product (MOD07_L2) in R. There's something going wrong during data import. The below code can be reproduced using one example .hdf file (MOD07_L2.A2013001.0835.006.2013001192145.hdf) that can be downloaded from [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nz6p2011od0bmn4/MOD07_L2.A2013001.0835.006.2013001192145.hdf).

```
library(rgdal)

# Extraction of metadata via `GDALinfo`    
filename <- "MOD07_L2.A2013001.0835.006.2013001192145.hdf"
gdalinfo <- GDALinfo(filename, returnScaleOffset = FALSE)
metadata <- attr(gdalinfo, "subdsmdata")

# Extraction of SDS string for parameter 'Skin_Temperature' (formerly 'Surface_Temperature')    
sds <- metadata[grep("Skin_Temperature", metadata)[1]]
sds <- sapply(strsplit(sds, "="), "[[", 2)

# Raster import via `readGDAL`   
sds.rg <- readGDAL(sds)
```

So far, so good, but here comes the confusing part:

```
> summary(sds.rg$band1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
 -14870  -14850  -14850  -14840  -14840  -14820   53529
```

Considering the fact that Skin_Temperature has an official valid range from 150 to 350 K (see [MOD07_L2:Format & Content](http://modis-atmos.gsfc.nasa.gov/MOD07_L2/format.html)), the mean would inherit a value of

```
> (-14840 - (-15000)) * 0.01
[1] 1.6
```

after considering the corresponding add_offset (-15000) and scale_factor (0.01). Note that we're still talking about Kelvin, not °C. Extracting SDS No. 8, i.e. Skin_Temperature, using

```
library(gdalUtils)
gdal_translate(filename, dst_dataset = "tmp.tif", sd_index = 8)
```

and opening the resulting file called "tmp.tif" in QGIS resulted in seemingly reliable values centered around 15000, i.e. roughly 27 °C. However, importing "tmp.tif" back into R using `raster` again resulted in values comparable to the ones shown above:

```
> summary(raster("tmp.tif"))
              tmp
Min.    -14867.31
1st Qu. -14848.13
Median  -14845.89
3rd Qu. -14840.53
Max.    -14819.93
NA's         0.00
```

I've been searching the internet and stumbled across [similar problems related to rgdal](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-sig-geo/098mmnbt41/rgdal-and-unsigned-integers). However, when I tried to cast `toUnSigned` on band 1 of my previously generated 'SpatialGridDataFrame', I received the following error message:

```
> toUnSigned(sds.rg$band1, 16)
Error in toUnSigned(sds.rg$band1, 16) : band not integer
```

Apparently, the data imported into R is not even of type integer (what it is supposed to be), but numeric:

```
> sds.rg$band1[1:5]
[1]        NA        NA -14839.40 -14840.25 -14839.26
```

Is there an apparent mistake in my code, or is there any point I miss when importing the .hdf and .tif files using `rgdal`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is surprisingly simple.

```
sgr_lst <- readGDAL(sds, as.is = TRUE)
```

solves the issue. The only thing left to do then is transform the resulting `SpatialGridDataFrame` to a proper `Raster*` object using `raster()`. For this purpose, it is necessary to retrieve the west, east, south, and north bounding coordinates (see `?extent`: xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) from the metadata e.g. via

```
meta <- attr(gdalinfo, "mdata")

## string patterns
crd_str <- paste0(c("WEST", "EAST", "SOUTH", "NORTH"), "BOUNDINGCOORDINATE")
## search for patterns in metadata
crd_id <- sapply(crd_str, function(i) grep(i, meta))
## extract information
crd <- meta[crd_id]
## create 'extent' object
crd <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(crd, "="), "[[", 2))
ext <- extent(crd)
```

The thus determined extent (together with the EPSG code) can then be passed on to the finally created `RasterLayer` which, after applying the scale factor and offset, definitely looks fine now.

```
## rasterize, apply offset and scale factor
rst_lst <- (raster(sgr_lst) - -1.5e+04) * 1.0e-02
## set extent and coordinate reference system
extent(rst_lst) <- crd
projection(rst_lst) <- "+init=epsg:4326"
```

[image: lst]

Answer (score 2):

I have not managed to do it in R either.. and I have also spent countless hours. What I do now is this:

1. Use the ModisReprojectionTool to extract the layers and the
   subsets I need as binary files
2. read the binary files and if necessary convert them to "raster" objects. I mainly use them 
   as matrix and in the end transform them into raster-objects to write them as TIFF

the code to run MRT:

```
# Reproject from HDF to plain binary with MRT
setwd('/Volumes/Archive1/MOD11C3V5/')
DIR <- getwd()
# Run the Modis Reprojection Tool once with one HDF-file and save the desired parameterization in a .prm-file
# Use this .prm-file here:
ReprojectionParamter <- 'Pamir0.05_binray.prm'

# Getting the file list that you want to process
FileList <- list.files()
FileListHDF <- FileList[which(regexpr(pattern='hdf$',FileList)>0)] # only the hdf-files but not the hdf.xml files

### Setting environmental variables for MRT_DATA_DIR
Sys.setenv(MRT_DATA_DIR='/Volumes/DATA/ModisReprojectionTool/data')
Sys.setenv(MRTDATADIR='/Volumes/DATA/ModisReprojectionTool/data')

for (i in FileListHDF){
  system(command=paste('/Volumes/DATA/ModisReprojectionTool/bin/resample -p ',ReprojectionParamter,' -i ',DIR,'/',i,' -o ',DIR,'/binary_small/',i,'.hdr',sep=''),wait=T,)
}
```

Then you have to set the "what" argument of readBin to int, numeric, etc... I always have the same extent of my files (defined in the "prm"-file) I get the extent and resolution directly from there:

```
ReprojectionParamter <- scan('Pamir0.05_binary2.prm', nmax=90,what='character')
SpatExtent.minLon <- as.numeric(ReprojectionParamter[31])
SpatExtent.minLat <- as.numeric(ReprojectionParamter[36])
SpatExtent.maxLon <- as.numeric(ReprojectionParamter[37])
SpatExtent.maxLat <- as.numeric(ReprojectionParamter[30])
SpatExtent.RES <- as.numeric(ReprojectionParamter[72])
# readBinary function
UInt8_LST <- function(f, ...) readBin(f, what = "integer", signed = FALSE, endian = "little", size = 2, ...)
# Finally read the data; Nlat,Nlon etc you can calculate easily from the info in the prm-file; 0.02 was my scale factor
NC.LST_night <- matrix(UInt8_LST(f=LST_night.filename, n= Nlon*Nlat)),nrow=Nlat,ncol=Nlon,byrow=T)*0.02-273.15
```

Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to say that [fdetsch's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/184044/107424) may not be correct because the extent created from `lonmin`, `lonmax`, `latmin`, `latmax` may not match with the actual grid boundary. The image is usually tilted.

The dropbox link is invalid so I download the same date file (updated version) from [here](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/61/MOD07_L2/2013/001/)

Below is what I plotted with fdetsch's code:

[image]

Below is my code and plot:

```
hdfname="MOD07_L2.A2013001.0835.061.2017296134818.hdf"
GDALinfo(hdfname, returnScaleOffset = FALSE) 
#note that the 29th and 30th subdatasets are lat and lon
one <- getSds(hdfname)    
lat=raster(readGDAL(one$SDS4gdal[29], as.is = TRUE))
lon=raster(readGDAL(one$SDS4gdal[30], as.is = TRUE))
Skin_Temperature <- brick(readGDAL(one$SDS4gdal[8], as.is = TRUE))
Skin_Temperature <- (Skin_Temperature - (-15000))*0.009999999776482582 #It seems that the scaling factor changed after data updates
color <- rev(terrain.colors(100))[as.numeric(cut(Skin_Temperature[],breaks = 100))]
plot(lon[],lat[],pch=20,col = color,xlab="lon",ylab="lat") #my plot
```

[image]